# Repository for mongock-core 4.3.8

Tags: maven, mongock

I try to update my mongock-core dependency to 4.3.8 (from 3.3.2) but it does not find the jar for the dependency.
So i have checked on the maven central repository i am using   (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) and i see that 3.3.2 indeed has the .jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/cloudyrock/mongock/mongock-core/3.3.2/
but 4.3.8 does not:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/cloudyrock/mongock/mongock-core/4.3.8/
Why is it so, and how do one include the dependency of 4.3.8 in this case?
The inclusion in pom.xml was done this way (with the value of mongokc version i changed from 3.3.2):

```
<properties>
...
        <mongock.version>4.3.8</mongock.version>
...
</properties>
... 
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${mongock.version}</version>
</dependency> 
...
<repository>
    <id>my-maven</id>
    <name>Maven Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Is something wrong with my inclusion or does something changed and need to be done differently now?

Answer (score 0):

Mongock's v4 usage differs a bit from v3. Please refer to the documentation on the following link:

[Mongock v4 Documentation](https://docs.mongock.io/v4/quick-start/index.html)

Once you have upgraded to v4.3.8, we recommend you to upgrade to Mongock's current version (v5.x.x). Please refer to the migration guide on the following link:

[Mongock v4 to v5 migration guide](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/from-version-4-to-5/index.html)

Comment: i try to, but when i put the dependencies in the pom.xml they are not downloaded. or  at least i don't know where they are as i can not find them in .m2\repository\com\github\cloudyrock\mongock (only mongock-bom and mongock-core are created and they do not contain jars) .  
i put them in this way:  
```
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>  
 <artifactId>mongock-standalone</artifactId>  
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also Version 4 doucmentation states that changelogs should be used like this:
@ChangeLog(order = "001")
but there is not a single ChangeLog class in the sources when i look at source code (https://github.com/mongock/mongock/tree/version4) is this normal?

Comment: Please take a look to our v4 sample projects in the following link: https://github.com/mongock/mongock-examples/tree/version4